# assigning an iterator to the next element in a list

Tags: c++, list, iterator

Given a list `std::list<std::string> _dailyList; {"Toyota", "Nissan","Ford"}` and an iterator `std::list<std::string>::iterator _nowServicing;` How would I implement a function `void RepairList::next()` If the iterator is pointing to `"Toyota"` and I call it, it will now point to `"Nissan"` and if I call it again it will now point to `"Ford"` basically moving to the right every time it is called.

````
void RepairList::next() {

//some code

}
```
````

Comment: This question is very similar to your question that was [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64564049/how-to-assign-an-iterator-to-the-next-element-in-a-list) for lack of clarity. Somehow, providing even less code made this one clearer. :-) The comment I made to your previous question was: "_I have trouble understanding what you are trying to do with the code above but wouldn't. `void RepairList::next() { ++_nowServicing; }` do what you want? `_nowServicing` would have to be initialized at some point though. Perhaps in the constructor._" - Did you even try that?

Answer (score 2):

You can increment the iterator with

```
void RepairList::next() {
    ++_nowServicing;
}
```

Comment: May need something to handle roll-over back to Toyota or trap overflow. Question's a bit fuzzy on that.

Comment: @user4581301 _"basically moving to the right"_ No rollover mentioned.

Comment: Agreed, but that comment is meant more for them than for you.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah, ok. I understood.

Comment: @ThomasSablik there is no need to assign _nowServing to _dailyList.begin() ?

Comment: @cppnoob not in `RepairList::next`. Your question is _"How would I implement a function `void RepairList::next()` If the iterator is pointing to "Toyota" ..."_. I'm assuming the iterator is correctly initialized.